# checking and unchecking md-checkbox using the id from angular 2(or 4) code

Tags: angular, material-design

```
<md-checkbox [align]="end" *ngFor="issueConfid in issueConfidences" (change)=onIssueConfidenceFilterChange(issueConfid)" id="favoriteCheck1.name">

 {{issueConfid.name}} 

</md-checkbox>
```

i want to uncheck(or check) the above md-checkbox from my angular 2 code 
ex: angular.getElementById('x').uncheck();
Please tell the right way if there is any to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `checked` property to the template and then change its value from inside the component.

> Template

```
<md-checkbox [checked]="checkBoxChecked" [align]="end" *ngFor="issueConfid in issueConfidences" (change)=onIssueConfidenceFilterChange(issueConfid)" id="favoriteCheck1.name">

 {{issueConfid.name}} 

</md-checkbox>
```

> Component

```
checkBoxChecked = false; // or true based on the need

checkCheckBoxProgrammatically(check: boolean) {
 this.checkBoxChecked = check ? true : false;
}
```

**EDIT**

If that didn't work you can use `ngModel` directive and assign the `boolean' variable to it.

```
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkBoxChecked" [align]="end" *ngFor="issueConfid in issueConfidences" (change)=onIssueConfidenceFilterChange(issueConfid)" id="favoriteCheck1.name">

 {{issueConfid.name}} 

</md-checkbox>
```

The value can be set dynamically using `checkCheckBoxProgrammatically(true/false)` method which in turn sets the `checkBoxChecked` property.

**EDIT_2**

```
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="issueConfid.checkBoxChecked" [align]="end" *ngFor="issueConfid in issueConfidences; let i = index" (change)=onIssueConfidenceFilterChange(issueConfid)" id="favoriteCheck1.name">

 {{issueConfid.name}} <div (click)="reset(i)">Reset</div>

</md-checkbox>
<div (click)="resetAll()">Reset All</div>
```

Have your `issueConfidences` list modified to have a `checkBoxChecked` property on all elements within it,

```
this.issueConfidences = [ {..., checkBoxChecked: true}, ... ,{..., checkBoxChecked: false} ];
reset(index: number) {
 this.issueConfidences[index].checkBoxChecked = false;
}
resetAll() {
 this.issueConfidences.forEach((issueConfid) => { issueConfid.checkBoxChecked = false; });
}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: this doesnot work, as the checkBoxChecked value should be a variable which should be bindable

Comment: Updated my answer. Please see if that helps.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate your help but the issue here is, I want the variable 'checkBoxChecked' should be different for each iteration(ex: issueConfid.id) so that I could uncheck from other events like ex: resetting the particular checkbox, I want jquery like functionality Ex; $("#id").hide() or $("#id").toggle().... or document.getElementById('id').checked = true...

Comment: It is doable to refer to particular elements in a template array through their template `id`s but not recommended by angular. You can likely integrate this `checkBoxChecked` for each element in the list by adding it as a property to the `issueConfidences`. Or if that is not what you need may be if you could specify on what kind of `events` they are for which you want this value to be modified then may be we could look into that.

Comment: Note : (change)=onIssueConfidenceFilterChange(issueConfid)" this is only one time binding and if we use ngModel it will affect all the elements inside the loop

Comment: I want one or any or all checkbox to be unchecked  from a button click 'reset all checkboxes' or 'reset particular checkbox' in the loop

Comment: Updated my answer, see EDIT_2. I have used 2 new methods `reset()` (within each element of the list in template and `resetAll()` (outside the list) this time to show the usage.

Comment: Ya bro, the resetAll() works, thank you but I want rest(i) button to be outside the list not inside, like here in this case a close icon in a md-chip

Comment: Is your `md-chip` also part of a list (`ngFor`) in the template?

Comment: md-chip is part of md-chip-list which is outside the template md-checkbox

Comment: So is there 1 `md-chip` item for each element of the `issueConfidences` list? Is that the idea? Then you could use the same concept above for implementing it.

Comment: '(change)=onIssueConfidenceFilterChange(issueConfid)" ' this function adds or removes chips to the chip list viz. <md-chip-list class="mat-chip-list-stacked">
        <md-chip *ngFor="let chip of filterChips" selected="false" removable="true">
          {{chip.name}}
          <i class="material-icons" (click)="removeFilterChipsItem(chip)">close</i>
        </md-chip>
      </md-chip-list>   clicking on 'removeFilterChipsItem(chip)' should remove chip and uncheck the checkbox